# Lodash to find and display json data that present

Tags: javascript, lodash

In below code "answer" key is present in 2nd & 4th Object but when i run code i just get 2nd object as output.

Expected output is object which has "answer" needs to be displayed

```js
    var users = [{
 "answerLength": "10",
 "isComment": "false",
 "question": "what?",
 "uniqueId": "01"
}, {
 "answerLength": "10",
 "isComment": "false",
 "question": "what?",
 "uniqueId": "aaa",
  "answer": "02"
}, {
 "answerLength": "10",
 "isComment": "false",
 "question": "what?",
 "uniqueId": "03"
}, {
 "answerLength": "10",
 "isComment": "false",
 "question": "what?",
 "uniqueId": "aaa",
  "answer": "04"
}];

function checkAnsExist(){
    var forEach = _.find(users, _.forEach(function(i){ return i.answer}));
    document.write(JSON.stringify(forEach));
}
checkAnsExist();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter), not `find`

```js
    var users = [{
 "answerLength": "10",
 "isComment": "false",
 "question": "what?",
 "uniqueId": "01"
}, {
 "answerLength": "10",
 "isComment": "false",
 "question": "what?",
 "uniqueId": "aaa",
  "answer": "02"
}, {
 "answerLength": "10",
 "isComment": "false",
 "question": "what?",
 "uniqueId": "03"
}, {
 "answerLength": "10",
 "isComment": "false",
 "question": "what?",
 "uniqueId": "aaa",
  "answer": "04"
}];

function checkAnsExist(){
    var forEach = _.filter(users, 'answer');
    document.write(JSON.stringify(forEach));
}
checkAnsExist();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any idea how do i write unit test case for same in mocha